# Unwanted items in Eclipse XML content assist

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, content-assist

I've defined a template to use to help typing out XML string definitions, which I've given the name "astring". In Content Assist, I've turned off `XML Tag Proposals`:

[image]

But I still get these two extraneous options "string" and "comment" coming up as the top suggestions when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Why does unchecking "XML Tag Proposals" and changing the order have no effect?

---

**update**:

1) It seems like the extra XML **tag proposals** only appear in the Android XML editor, not the "standard" one

2) However I get extra **template proposals** coming up in both editors, until I type some extra characters to narrow down the name.

I am not sure if this is a bug or by design. I think a bug, because I would expect it work like the Java completion whereby it takes into account the characters already typed, as soon as I press the completion key.

So a workaround for the normal XML editor is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> *before* starting to type the name of your template. But you still get the Tag Proposals in the Android XML editor.

Should I enter this as a bug in Eclipse or in the Android plug-in, or both?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Report it at http://bugs.eclipse.org/ .

Comment: @nitind thanks. I've put some more details above.

Comment: @nitind btw, if I enter a bug, which eclipse project should it be reported under?

Comment: After your edits, it sound more like an ADT bug (if it doesn't happen in the stock XML Editor).  There's not a separate Android XML template page?

Comment: @nitind no, there's no separate Android XML template page. I think there are 2 bugs here. 1) Android XML editor shows tag proposals even when you've turned them off. 2) Standard XML editor (and Android one) doesn't filter template proposals list based on characters already entered when code-complete key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any default XML templates (XML / XML Files / Templates) that might be similar to the tag proposals?

You can also check Windows > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations and switch to a different XML editor of your liking.

As a last resort, try changing the locale to English/US temporarily to avoid a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=244667) and restart Eclipse.  Visit Control Panel; Region/Language, Administrative (or Advanced); Language for non-Unicode Programs; Change system locale.

Comment: That bug was closed in 2008. I tried changing the locale and it didn't help. :(

Comment: @LuigiPlinge - Apologies, it was probably just a silly idea of mine.  I added two more things to try to the answer and if it doesn't help you even then I'm gonna delete it as garbage, so you might want to incorporate the things you've unsuccessfully tried into the body of your question.  Let me know.